# Why in GDB, the value of "frame at" is different from the value of ebp($fp) register?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, stack

I'm trying to understand basic assembly language by looking into the stack frame information in GDB. I tried to find what happened when a function is called by main function.

But I find that the value of "frame at" in the "info frame" is different from the value of ebp register in the "info reg". By convention, shouldn't these two value both indicate the start point of a stack frame and be identical?

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xffffced8:
...
(gdb) info reg
esp            0xffffcec0   0xffffcec0
ebp            0xffffced0   0xffffced0
```

I guess it is because the address from 0xffffced8 to 0xffffced0 is used to store data such as returning address and input parameters? How can I verify my idea？

Answer (score 4):

GDB defines the frame address as “the address of the memory location after the last word belonging to the frame.“ http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/info_frame

(This may be architecture specific. ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_7.html)